# Flex Mobile, Get Value data from SpinnerList

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

When i using 1st code it works, return me the value. but, if i change

list="{new ArrayList(['test1','test2'])}"

to

list="{Operation1Result2.lastResult}

the return value just like [object songvoting]

---

```
protected function spinnerList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {               
            Debug.text  = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;
        }

<s:SpinnerListContainer includeIn="vote" x="10" y="100" width="640" height="446">
    <s:SpinnerList id="spinnerList" width="636" height="443"
                   creationComplete="spinnerList_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                   labelField="song" selectedIndex="1" textAlign="center"
                   change="spinnerList_changeHandler(event)">                   
        <s:AsyncListView list="{new ArrayList(['test1','test2'])}"/>            
    </s:SpinnerList>
</s:SpinnerListContainer>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of "Operation1Result2.lastResult" ? To me, this looks like a single Object and not like an IList.

Comment: this is service for get the http-json, spinner works fine,gave me everything on the spinner list.

Comment: label.text = Operation1Result2.lastResult the output just like [object blabla],[object balbala],[object blalaa]

Comment: list="{Operation1Result2.lastResult}" or dataProviderlist="{Operation1Result2.lastResult}" on Spinnerlist/ColumnChart it will return the value on the Spinnerlist/ColumnChart

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, "Operation1Result2.lastResult" returns an IList of songvoting-Objects, while new ArrayList(['test1','test2']) is just an IList of Strings, right?

Comment: Yupp, so the data on spinnerlist got from http-jon. oh ya, i just find out my code works  by change the  Debug.text  = event.currentTarget.selectedItem to  Debug.text  = spinnerList..selectedItem.song;

Comment: That would have been my next question :)